# How to say "I finished my working day" in a simpler way?

Tags: word-choice

How do you say ***I finished my working day just now.**
(When the clock strikes five, and you try to message your family you are ready to set off from the office)*?

Does the below sound fine?

> **I am off now**, I will be home in no time.
>
> **I just got off**, I will be home in no time.

Comment: Text msg or voicemail?  Both are fine.  Since it's family you can be informal "I'm off now..." and "I'll be home..."

Comment: _"I just got off"_ is okay, but you should know that the expression "get off" has [another slang meaning](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20off) that you might want to avoid, which is why some might perfer to say, _"I just got off **work**"_ instead. Also, there are quite a few playful ways to express it; anyone who grew up watching _The Flintstones_ might just type: [Yabba-Dabba-Doo!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpGx4foRdPw).

Comment: How about *On my way home. Be there in 10.*

Comment: My experience is that when I'm punching a timecard or working required hours, I tend to use *I just got off work and am on my way home*, but when I'm working a salaried job with no fixed hours I just use, "I'm on my way home."

Comment: _I'm done (with work) (today/this week); I'm off work; I'm outta here._

Comment: *Ah, just leaving the office.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any one of the suggested phrases above sound good to me (British), including your original offerings. They don't come much simpler than that, except maybe:

> I'm just leaving/I've just finished

Since your family undoubtedly know what you have just finished (or where you're leaving from).

I'd simply like to add a few more alternatives to the list.

1. I've just clocked off.
2. I've just punched out.
3. I've just got out of work
4. I've just knocked off.
5. Just left. Get a beer out and the dinner on.

Comment: "I'm just leaving" sounds somewhat ambiguous to my ears. I first interpreted it as "I'm only leaving".

Comment: Fair enough but I'd still argue most native speakers would understand it in the intended way.